# Automatic startup network interface in LXC container

Tags: networking, startup, lxc, proxmox

I have a fedora 27 LXC container inside a proxmox VE 5.1

The network config is working fine, I've added a Linux Bridge using the subnet 172.27.1.0/24 and the container is "connected" to the network.

The problem is that when I reboot the container the network interface is always down, if I execute:

```
ifup eth0
```

The interface is UP again and all seems OK.

The command `ip addr` shows:

```
# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
48: eth0@if49: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:7a:b1:2c:f7:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.27.1.2/24 brd 172.27.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::307a:b1ff:fe2c:f7a2/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

How can I configure proxmox to activate the interface automatically on container startup ?

*UPDATE*: I've configured new containers but using CentOS 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 images, using the same Linux Bridge and the network interface is activated automatically, so the problem seems related with the fedora image...

Info about the lxc tools installed in the proxmox host:

```
# dpkg -l|grep lxc
ii  lxc-pve                              2.1.1-3                        amd64        Linux containers usersapce tools
ii  lxcfs                                2.0.8-2                        amd64        LXC userspace filesystem
```

Comment: Unfortunately with the new LXC 2.x being built around LXD (the daemon) and named LXD with a client program called `lxc` such a question is rather difficult to answer without further info. However, I happened to have PVE 5.1 running and checked: it's using LXC 1.x.

Comment: Hi @0xC0000022L, what kind of info do you need ? Theorically Proxmox VE 5.1 uses LXC 2.1, according to the Release notes: https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Roadmap#Proxmox_VE_5.1

Comment: well, try it: `dpkg -l|grep lxc`. On my installation that only gives me two packages: `lxc-pve` and `lxcfs`. At least the LXC tools installed are the LXC 1.x tools. Kind of makes sense, seeing as PVE is a Debian derivative and [LXD](https://wiki.debian.org/LXD) is so far mostly big on Ubuntu, but not on Debian. In fact `apt-get update && apt-get install lxd` gives `E: Unable to locate package lxd`. Also see `dpkg -L lxc-pve` ... the only listed tools are from the LXC 1.x tool set (which *is* compatible with LXC 2.x).